# WP8.1 - Implementation of ListView to display a list of countries

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

In my WP8.1 RT project, I am trying to implement a ListView that displays a list of countries. (For now) I have a three page setup: P1 has a hyperlink button that takes you to P2, that has a ListView (with which I'd be binding the list of all countries), which, when selected, takes you to p3, that has it's own stuffs going on there. The articles I've gone through are the ones where the ListView is not a multipage layout. It is usually a single page one. It gets difficult because a lot of factors. I would like your help in determining a few things because of that..

1. Can I have a multipage (three-page lay out in my case) layout containing a ListView. Also, considering, I might have to use the item selected in the list, on another page (say P4 or P5, even P3 perhaps).
2. Is it ok to have the list of the countries hard-coded (i know it is exhausting to even think of it) to the ListView, for an app that has a very minimal use (say a social networking stuff)?
3. If not, do you prefer I have the names of the countries in a Model (MVVM setup), say in a .cs file, and have that exposed to the XAML? - This I've tried and has worked, but not very well, UI-wise.
4. If not that also, do you prefer I have them listed in an XML file and parse through them? - This, I haven't tried, and would need some guidance.
5. What'd be the convenient way of accomplishing this: p1 (hyperlink button) -> p2 (shows a list of countries; makes a selection) -> P3 (it's own stuffs)?

Oh, another thing: The reason I need the listview is because I need to implement the semantic zoom feature to display the countries.

Thank you for your help in advance :)